# how to get a specific logging config in pythong logging

Tags: python-logging

I am trying to find a way to get a specific logging config.

Here is how I set the logging config:

```
config = {"version":1, "verbosity": 12}
logging.config.dictConfig(config)
```

I'd like some way to get the value of `verbosity` through `logging`, like `logging.config.get("verbosity")`

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Access you value like this:

```
print "Value of verbosity is: %s" %  config.get('verbosity')
```

Comment: Clarified the question a bit. But I am not talking how to get a property from a dict.

Comment: Try to paste my code inside the appropriate logging function, without the "print".

Comment: Sorry, I guess I still missed your point. Could you elaborate on it?

Comment: i am not sure which logging function / package is best in your case, but the philosophy is logging_funxtion(config.get('verbosity')). comprende amigo?